# How to debug services in Debian if they fail to start

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I have a new Debian unstable based distro with apache2 on it. Apache itself is working fine. If i use

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

it comes up and everything goes well.

But the service for it fails to start every boot.

How to trace the error here?

etc/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Sun Jan 15 14:51:06.685936 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2208] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 15 14:51:47.842447 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2200] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 15 14:51:48.145808 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 15 14:55:25.766188 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3257] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 15 14:55:25.801736 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3257] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 15 16:08:15.031691 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2316] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 15 16:08:15.043756 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2316] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 16 11:26:33.007967 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2278] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 16 11:26:33.013972 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2278] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
 [Tue Jan 17 08:07:35.149382 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3517] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Tue Jan 17 08:07:35.152372 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3517] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

What other files would be helpful to debug the service failure?

Answer (score 4):

1. Check that service enabled by run `systemctl --no-page -t service -a
   | grep apache2`
2. If it disabled, enable it and start: `systemctl enable apache2 &&
   systemctl start apache2`
3. Check that service works `systemctl status apache2`
4. If need you can check apache2.service related logs with: `journalctl
   --no-page -u apache2.service` *Note*. `-f` key works with `journalctl` well as with `tail`

Answer (score 3):

There is no failure the system is working as designed. It sounds like you probably just need to *enable* the service so it starts at boot.

```
systemctl enable service
```

You may want to spend some time with the systemctl/systemd documentation.